# How to update NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

I have to update an element in that dictionary. How i can do that?

Comment: depends what you mean by update...

Comment: i have to remove an object and insert another value for a key.This NSMutableDictionary is a plist of application  settings of user. User  will change it frequently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please refer to the [API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject:forKey:) here

First retrieve the objects using

```
[dict objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Later, you can set them back using:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

Comment: thanks. i tried like this. it worked..
[plistDict removeObjectForKey:@"name"] ;
[plistDict setObject:@"my name" forKey:@"name"];

Comment: You don't need to remove the object for a key before setting the new value.

Comment: i need only  [plistDict setObject:@"my name" forKey:@"name"]; ? ok. i will try this .Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

dictionary only allows you to have one objects for each key so if you use "set object for key" it will update the current one

Answer (score 2):

NSMutableDictionary's method *addEntriesFromDictionary*.

> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the new value object takes its place.